# Reading REST response from NSstring on Java Backend

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am getting the following error when I try to read the response from a get at my server:

```
JSON
Error: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at  1 [character 2 line 1]
```

The client is an IOS app written in Objective C. I am sending an NSString with the following encoding:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is the nslog output of that NSString:

```
{
 "longitude" : "-122.03121860000000253876",
 "latitude" : "37.33233141000000188114"
}
```

Here is my get function at the java server:

```
  @GET
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String get(String result) throws JSONException, IOException {
      JSONObject sit = null;          
      try {
          System.out.println(result + "JSON");
          sit = new JSONObject(result);
          System.out.println("Success: json = ");
          System.out.println(sit.toString(2));
        } catch(JSONException ex) {
          System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    return this.dBQ.getSItems(sit).toString();
  }
```

I am wondering if you guys can point me in the right direction.Ironically enough I am able to get the response from the server from the client. But for some reason the variable result in my java function ( at the server) outputs as empty and spits out an exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I answered my own question I used a post request with the following code:

```
  private DBQuery dBQ = new DBQuery();
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String getresponses(String si) {
      return this.dBQ.getItems(si).toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to look up `org.json.JSONObject` - that is Android API, right? Why do you use that in your backend?

Anyway, looking at the [JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) of the constructor you use, it says:

> Parameters json   String: a **JSON-encoded string** containing an object.

Your `result` string already got parsed by JAX-RS, so it's just the naked text without curly braces. So I'd say that's why you're getting the exception.

Like I mentioned, I really don't know Android API, but if you really must use it, you should try [`JSONObject.quote(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to wrap your string first before passing it to the constructor.

Comment: Nope it is the jersey api. I am writing the backend in Java. And for whatever reason the result string doesn't output anything. Can I get a response on a get. I am new to this. I will try it out with a post.